# multiple background pics in css

Tags: css, background, hover

this is what im trying to do...

```
ul#newnav a{ /*--This is basically the hover state of navigation--*/
color: #555;
background: url(images/a_bg.gif) repeat-x left bottom;}

ul#newnav a{ background: url(images/navpic.png) no-repeat top left;}
```

and of course its only loading the last one but is it anyway I can load both.

Comment: Why would you load both?  Are you trying to layer them?

Comment: yea one is the actual background that repeats and the other is a pic that dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :hover pseudo class

```
ul#newnav a{ background: url(images/navpic.png) no-repeat top left;}

ul#newnav a:hover { /*--This is basically the hover state of navigation--*/
color: #555;
background: url(images/a_bg.gif) repeat-x left bottom;}
```

See [**The dynamic pseudo-classes: :hover, :active, and :focus**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

In CSS3 you can have multiple backgrouds for an element

See **[Multiple backgrounds with CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)**

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, you can only one background at a time.   You can try to have multiple layers and put backgrounds in each layer, if they contain transparencies.